# How to migrate CLOB column to (json) BLOB in DB2 without truncating data?

Tags: json, db2, blob, clob

I have a DB2 11 database with a large table that has JSON data stored in a CLOB column. Given that I'd like to perform queries on it using the JSON_VAL function, I always need to use JSON2BSON to convert it first, which I assume is a significant overhead. I would like to move the data into another table that has exactly the same structure, except for the CLOB column which I'd like to replace with a BLOB one to store the JSON immediately in BLOB, hoping that this will speed up my queries.

My approach to this was writing a

```
insert into newtable (ID, BLOBDATA) select ID, SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON(CLOBDATA) from oldtable;
```

After doing this I realized that long json objects got truncated. I have googled on this and learned that selects to truncate large objects.

I am reaching out to here to see if there is any simple way for me to do this excercise, without having to write a program to read out and write back all the data. (I had myself burnt with similar truncation taking place when I used DB2 csv export features.)

Thanks.

Comment: How large are the CLOB and BLOB columns, which defined size?

Comment: 32Mb is their defined max size. I think it gets truncated with my approach at 16 or 32k

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Db2 11.1.4.4 there are [new JSON functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/c0061252.html) based on the ISO technical paper. I would advise to use them. They are the strategic functionality going forward.

You could use [JSON_VALUE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070417.html?pos=2) to perform the equivalent of what you planned to with JSON_VAL.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Do you know anything about the performance difference between using JSON_VALUE over text or binary stored data? Apart from this workaround I am still interested in how to solve the original problem

Comment: According to IBM presentations query performance for JSON data stored as BSON is better, but it takes some more time to initially store them (compared to text JSON).